# constexpr in class without static

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I need to store a compile time constant in a header, and I do it in the class I'm using it in as **I don't want to expose the constant to other files that include this header**. (as well as the fact that it depends on another hidden struct)

Like this:

```
namespace ns {
    class bla {
    private:
        struct internalStruct {
            // ...
        };

        // I put it in the class as I don't want other files to be able to see this
        constexpr const size_t compileConstant = sizeof(internalStruct) * 8;
    };
}
```

The problem is I get a

```
Constexpr is not valid here
```

error. The solution is to add `static`, however I read that `constexpr` integral members should be inline.

What should I do?

Comment: _I don't want to expose the constant._: It's `private`, what is your problem?

Comment: *"however I read that `constexpr` integral members should be inline."* So what? Why do you think this is a problem? *Bonus reading material: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and look for the phrase "implies inline". Not just "should be" inline, but in fact **are** inline.*

Comment: Using static constexpr is the correct way. constexpr is alreay const & expr so you don't need to use extra const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding static should be perfectly fine for your use case. That's what the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#:%7E:text=A%20constexpr%20specifier%20used%20in%20a%20function%20or%20static%20data%20member%20(since%20C%2B%2B17)%20declaration%20implies%20inline.) states too:

> A constexpr specifier used in a function or static data member (since
> C++17) declaration implies inline.

And since this is a compile-time constant, you might as well have it shared across all class instances rather than on a per-instance basis (which is usually how even `const` variables are used).

Comment: The reason I don't move the scope of the constant into the namespace is to prevent other files from seeing that constant, and also because that constant depends on the size of `internalStruct`, which I want to keep hidden aswell

Comment: I was referring to having the constant *within the class* by making it `static` when I referred to `sharing across all class instances`, not actually moving it to the outer namespace. That way you can access the private `internalStruct` from within the class, yet not expose it, just like you have it right now. As for the `inline` guarantee, that's in the answer.